# SVN update over salt stack

Tags: svn, salt-stack

I have a problem, I am updating many servers over SaltStack SVN.

Mostly all is ok, but some updates are failing.

```
servera:
    ERROR: svn: E000022: Error converting entry in directory '/var/www/site_front/public/css/images' to UTF-8
    svn: E000022: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8':
    svn: E000022: ?\226?\128?\143?\226?\128?\143?\215?\162?\215?\149?\215?\170?\215?\167 ?\215?\169?\215?\156 checkbox.png

    svn --non-interactive update
```

I have went and deleted the file, AND updated all servers manually and it's still happening.

Comment: Can you post your sls files and the command and output you're getting from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it's directly a salt issue, instead, it looks like it's potentially an issue with svn.

[Here's the exact error message you're seeing](http://scriptsdevelopers.com/solved-svn-issue-svn-e000022-cant-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-native-encoding/)

And the recommended solution is to put `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` into your environment.

It's hard for me to tell if this is actually your issue without more information, but if you find that it is, here's the beauty of salt: you can provision this.

Either use the [environ](http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.environ.html) state or the [file](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html) state and use the `- require` instruction in the state that's causing the issue in order to chain them in the correct order.